# How can you use one database with multisite

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins, multisite, content

I have two separate wordpress installations and two different domains. I am using one database with table prefixes. It works great but when I enter my content on one site it isn't reflected on the other site. I just need my content information (my posts, pages, custom content types, menus, and media) reflected on both sites; everything else (such as plugins, themes, and home pages) needs to be separate. I only want to have to enter the content information once; and possibly have the option of editing or creating on either domain.

Comment: Hi and welcome to WP.SE. Have you already taken a look at the [help] to see how the site works? Have you also already seen WordPress multisite installs (see wp.org Codex for that)?

Comment: I guess what I am asking is sure way of getting it done. I have searched everywhere and I am not sure if I should install multisite or not... I need help with determining that.

Comment: WordPress suggests having a unique database prefix for each site on your multisite.

Comment: @thatLeo.com Please read the question again.

Comment: You don't use a multisite installation. Multisite is one WordPress instance with different sites via back end. But you can merge your current 2 installs with one database in one Multisite installation and get the benefit of this one Multisite installation. Also you can use different domains for this different sites. It works on the core, no plugin required.

Comment: @beultge. How can I accomplish this. I tried to install multisite with the config files and .htaccess. Unfortunately, I received an error that there was already multisite previously installed so I couldn't continue with that (I also don't know how to fix that since I hadn't had multisite before). What I have also considered is using a sync plugin but that overwrites the entire database. I just need certain parts the same essentially.